Redirect all nonexistent subdomains trough masked redirect to main domain - wordpress
I run a wordpress website and I want to redirect all subdomains (e. g. www.anything.mydomain.com" to dislay the contents of mydomain.com. Is it possible? If not, how could I redirect all subdomain normally to main domain. I tried all the solutius but nothing worked. Here is my htacces file:
Thank you very much!
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

I tried to use this:
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.somnovozamcan.eu
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)\.somnovozamcan\.eu$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://somnovozamcan.eu/$1 [L,R=301,QSA]



You would not have to rewrite anything for this. You simply define the host serving the "main domain" as the default host inside your http server. That's all, then all requests to other domains will get handled by that host, thus serving the same content. Obviously you need to take care of the name resolution for all those names, that has nothing to do with your http server or rewriting, though.

In case you do not have control over the http server (for example when using a cheap hosting provider), it depends what options your provider offers. So we cannot answer that, you need to ask your hosting provider. A last option would be to proxy such requests, but that comes with a massive performance penalty.
